# In bash, how do I list environment variables matching "MY_VAR" and then export them?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to export all environment variables beginning with "MY_VAR_". 
How do I do this?

Comment: The variables whose _names_ begin with that, or the variables whose _values_ begin with that? Also, do you mean environment variables (exported shell variables) in particular, or just all shell variables?

Comment: Environment variables are already exported.  What do want to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 4):

As `export` of an already exported variable is no-op:

```
export "${!MY_VAR_@}"
```

Will export **all** variables that start with `MY_VAR_`.

---

If you only want the *list* of exported variables that start with `MY_VAR_`:

```
env | grep '^MY_VAR_'
```

Or (calling an external program only keeps exported variables):

```
bash -c 'printf %s\\n "${!MY_VAR_@}"'
```

---

Or, if you have `completion` available (it is loaded by default):

```
$ compgen -A export MY_VAR_
MY_VAR_aa
MY_VAR_bb
MY_VAR_ss
```

Comment: how about `sh -c 'echo ${!MY_VAR_@}'` for listing exported variables that start with `MY_VAR_`

Comment: @iruvar That will only work if `sh` is linked to `bash` and better that you quote the expansion of the variable: `bash -c 'printf %s\\n "${!MY_VAR_@}"'`.